# Python boto3 set lificycle on objects

Tags: python, amazon-s3

is it possible in python 2/boto3 to set life cycle for each uploaded object, using something similar to the permission setting done below?
Note - each one of uploaded objects may have different life cycle, hence, me trying to set those individually.

```
response = s3.put_object_acl(ACL='public-read', Bucket=bucket_name, Key=filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible, since there is no API to set lifecycle policies on individual objects: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectOps.html

What you can do is set the lifecycle policy on the bucket and apply rules based on object prefix and/or object tags: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/intro-lifecycle-rules.html

Comment: thanks, thats what i figured, but wanted to double check :(